# Jcombobox, when an item is selected, a value is displayed

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jcombobox

Basically, I have a `JComboBox` and currently, the selected value is then displayed next to the combo box in a text box.

However, what I would like to do, is upon selection of a value from the combo box - a different value is displayed in the text box (This displayed value is specific to the value selected from the combo box.

So in this case I have sizes in the combo box, and I want costs displayed in the text field.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ComboBox{
  JComboBox combo;
  JTextField txt;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ComboBox b = new ComboBox();
  }

  public ComboBox(){
    String course[] = {"18x18cm (7x7inches)","18x20cm (7x8inches)",};
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cost Calculator");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    combo = new JComboBox(course);
    combo.setBackground(Color.white);
    combo.setForeground(Color.black);
    txt = new JTextField(25);
    panel.add(combo);
    panel.add(txt);
    frame.add(panel);
    combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
        String str = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();
        txt.setText(str);
      }
    });
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

So my question is how do I go about this?

Comment: You already seem to know how to retrieve the selected value from the combobox, and how to update the textfield when this selection changes. So what is the question ? How to retrieve the cost when you have the size ? That is something we cannot answer with the code you posted

Comment: Ahh, see basically rather than having the identical copy of the value from the combobox replicated and displayed in the textfield, I want to select a value from the combobox and then have a value that is associated with that displayed in the textfield.


For example. Currently (comboxbox value=displayed text):
7x7cm=7x7cm

Instead I want to have:
7x7cm=£100

Comment: That was the part I understood. But how are we supposed to give you an answer with the available information in the question ... you are the only one who knows how to convert the 7*7cm to 100 pounds

Comment: Okay, I've updated the post with the full script. So basically for the three values in the original post the first would equal £122, second £114, third £116. The way the pricing works with the sizes isn't exactly consistent (I just have a table of "height to width" with the costs within). So do I have to make a separate string of values in the actionlistener that will then be displayed in the text field?                 So if "18x18cm (7x7inches)" is 0 in the combobox string, then "£122" is also 0 as it is the first value so it will be displayed. I'm sorry if I'm not being very clear ):

Comment: You can use java.util.Map for this, I guess if I understood your question and comments in the right sense. Get what you selected from the JComboBox and get the related value from the Map to display that in the JTextField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is make a new class so you can keep the data for the JComboBox and the JTextField tied to one another.

```
class MyClass{
    private String comboStr;
    private String textStr;

    public MyClass{
        comboStr = "this goes in my combobox";
        textStr = "this goes in my textfield";
     }

    public String toString(){
        return comboStr;
    }

    public String getText(){
         return textStr;
    }
}
```

(You need the toString() so that that each element in the combobox shows the correct text.)

Then in your listener, you can use the following to set the text for the JTextField.

```
MyClass myObj = (MyClass)combo.getSelectedItem();
txt.setText(myObj.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the `JComboBox` display different text, say `Google`, when there is an object there that has info about it, you need to override the `toString()` method in the class that is being added to the `JComboBox`. This is because when the `JComboBox` sets itself up, it uses the `toString()` method for every object in it to create the display text.